# Почему после запуска python прекращает работу

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyFirstProgramApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFirstProgramApp().run()
```

после запуска

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Марк\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-09-27_0.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Марк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Марк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
```

и python прекращает работу

Answer (score 0):

установить зависимости надо

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2 kivy_deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.17
```

Comment: Всё установлено, та же проблема

Comment: Вообще ни чего не поменялось?

Comment: абсолютно ничего, все уже было установлено